# Python: count frequency of words in a txt file

Tags: list, python-3.x, text-files, frequency

I am required to count the frequency of the key words from a text file. I am not allowed to use dictionaries or sets, and I also cannot import any Python methods. I honestly cannot figure out how to do it!!

This is how its supposed to display:

```
car 4
dog 4
egg 3
```

here's what i have so far, and it absolutely does not work.

```
fname = input("enter file name:")
ifile = open(fname, 'r')
list1 = ['car', 'dog', 'cat'.....'ect']
list2 = []

for word in ifile:
    if word in list1:
        list2.index(word)[1] += 1
    else:
        list2.append([word,])
```

print(list2,)

Comment: related: [Counting Things in Python: A History](http://treyhunner.com/2015/11/counting-things-in-python/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played with this a little... I noticed I had to enter file name in quotes for some reason.

```
fname = input('enter file name:')
ifile = open(fname, 'r')
list1 = []
list2 = []

for line in ifile.readlines():
    for word in line.split(' '):
        word = word.strip()
        if word in list1:
            list2[list1.index(word)] += 1
        else:
            list1.append(word)
            list2.append(1)


for item in list1:
    print item, list2[list1.index(item)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you can't use any set/list structures why not use another string and write the unique words encountered, incrementing on existence. Pseudocode:

- create empty string for storage
- parse and extract words
- iterate
- check word against string (if exists: increment / ifnot exists: add and set count to 1)
- output string